# Prolog: identify if two functors are identical *without* variable binding

Tags: prolog

So I have two lists:

```
[location(A),package(B)]
```

and

```
[location(C),package(B),truck(D)]
```

I want to add these together without adding identical terms.  That is, the result should be

```
[location(A),package(B),location(C),truck(D)] %Package B doesn't get repeated
```

I can write my own `remove_duplicates`, but it will identify `location(A)` as matching `location(C)`, and I need them both.

The purpose is to make a rule, later to be asserted, in which I may have multiple locations, packages, and trucks referenced.  The rule contains variables so it can match different states/situations with locations, packages, and trucks specified.  My learning algorithm adds preconditions to that rule as it searches for the right set of preconditions.

If this needs to be done with ground terms instead, I think I will have the problem that it must be variables at a later time.

Comment: `p(B) == p(B).` at the prompt succeeds, while `p(B) == p(C).` fails. This suggests you could use `==` in your predicate. (note that `B=C, p(B) == p(C).` succeeds, so do be careful not to unify  any variables). and it is not "functors" but "compound terms" you're referring to -- it is `p` that is the functor in the compound term `p(B)`.

Comment: There may be a simpler way, but you could use `=../2` to examine the term as a list, then compare each list element (arguments) using `==/2` rather than `=/2`.

Comment: In practise it is often necessary to find reasonable tradeoffs, including some hacks to cut some corners. Having said that, it seems you start the architectural "phase one: modeling" off by searching for workarounds. Warning: there's trouble ahead!

Comment: For instance, why you are sure about using (dynamic) asserted rules later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming order is not significant, a simple solution is to use the de facto standard `append/3` predicate and the standard `sort/2` predicate. For example:

```
| ?- append([location(A),package(B)], [location(C),package(B),truck(D)], List), sort(List, Sorted).

List = [location(A),package(B),location(C),package(B),truck(D)]
Sorted = [location(A),location(C),package(B),truck(D)]
```

Comment: Can you say why that works?  It seems sort is smart enough to know what's identical without unifying.  I might have a use for that in other contexts.

Comment: @TopologicalSort `sort/2`uses, per spec, term *equality*, not term *unification*. It also removes duplicated terms.

Comment: Looking up your terms, I see that = does *unification* and == does *equality*.  I ask you to put that in your answer, because that's what I was really getting at.  I'll accept your answer anyway, because it solves the problem neatly and directly, but for posterity I think it would be good to add that.